# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier when calling function declared in variable (and passing arguments through)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Javascript class/object to handle all my ajax requests with multiple methods/functions within it. I'm half way there however I've been stuck with the

> 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier'

When I'm trying to call a function named in an argument. I've looked around stackoverflow and haven't found a solution that works for me which means I've probably made a mistake somewhere that I cannot spot.

The function is designed to be used as follows:

```
ajax.post(url, POST data, onLoad callback function);
ajax.get(url, GET parameters, onLoad callback function);
//example:
ajax.get('http://api.domain.com/get', {x:1,y:2}, callback_function_when_complete);
```

You get the idea.. and the code:

```
ajax = {
    xhr: (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest(),
    readyStateCode: null,
    httpStatusCode: null,
    response: null,
    returnValue: function(onLoadCallbackFunction){
        switch (onLoadCallbackFunction, response) {
            case (typeof(onLoadCallbackFunction) != 'undefined'):
            case (onLoadCallbackFunction != null): 
                returnValue = response;
                console.log('Ajax onLoadCallbackFunction: No onload callback function called, returning response to caller.');
                break;

            case (onLoadCallbackFunction == false): 
                returnValue = true;
                console.log('Ajax onLoadCallbackFunction: Caller doesn\'t want response.')
                break;

            case (typeof(onLoadCallbackFunction) == "function")
                returnValue = onLoadCallbackFunction(response);
                console.log('Ajax onLoadCallbackFunction: Function specified, function called with response in arguments.');
                break;

            default:
                returnValue = false;
                console.log('Ajax onLoadCallbackFunction: Switch failed, returning false');
                break;
        }
        return returnValue;
    },
    get: function(url, parameters, onLoadCallbackFunction){
        if (typeof parameters != 'undefined' && parameters != null && parameters != ''){
            var str = [];
            for(var key in parameters)
            if (parameters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[key]));
            } 
            url = url + '?' + str.join("&");
        }

        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            this.readyStateCode = this.xhr.readyState;
            this.httpStatusCode = this.xhr.status;
        }

        this.xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        this.xhr.send();
        return this.returnValue(onLoadCallbackFunction, this.response);
    },
    post: function(url, data, onLoadCallbackFunction, mimeType){
        //todo mimeType
        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            this.readyStateCode = this.xhr.readyState;
            this.httpStatusCode = this.xhr.status;
        }

        this.xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        this.xhr.send(data);
        return this.returnValue(onLoadCallbackFunction, this.response);
    },
    upload: function(url, file, onLoadCallbackFunction, onStateChangeCallbackFunction){
        //todo
        //temporary
        return false;
    }
    //todo onerror handler
};
```

I'm getting thrown the error in my returnValue() function inside the switch case when returning a called function (well the parser is flagging it before it's even run too).

```
case (typeof(onLoadCallbackFunction) == "function")
    **returnValue = onLoadCallbackFunction(response);**
    //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier on line above
    //...
    break;
```

And yeah, I'm completely stuck right now, I'm aware I can use `eval()` but I **really** do not want to do that. It throws this error with and without arguments passed through it.

Sorry for the messiness and length of my code, it still needs tidying up.
Also, I'm a bit of a novice so if someone could explain where I'm going wrong that'd be very much appreciated, thanks in advance. Dan.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `:` after your case statement:

```
case (typeof(onLoadCallbackFunction) == "function"):
// ------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Oh dear me, always something small. Thank you so much haha

Comment: In general, be aware that many "unexpected X" errors are caused by the line immediately before it missing something ;)

Comment: It's always a missing line break or unclosed bracket, thanks for the heads up :)